# How to trigger material ui tab from url parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using Material UI and React Router, I need to be able to trigger a given tab based on a parameter in the url. For example: `someurl.com/page-name/tab-name`, where the route for `tab-name` would be used to select the associated tab on the page from the tab name in the url. Is this something React Router can do? I have checked the documentation and not found what I'm looking for.

I have tried this on one of the pages:

```
const urlParam = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
useEffect(() => {
    subNav.indexOf(urlParam) >- 1 && setValue(subNav.indexOf(urlParam));
  },[])
```

but the routing gets messed up when selecting a different route from the main navigation.

This is my current project structure:

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
....
....

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState('');

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <Drawer 
          style={{width: '240px'}}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={true}
          classes={{paper: classes.drawerPaper}}
        >
          <List>
            {data && data.navigation.map((item, i) =>
              <NavLink
                exact
                className={classes.link}
                activeClassName="selected"
                key={i}
                to={`${item.path}`}
              >
                <ListItem button selected={selectedIndex === i} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, i)}>
                  <ListItemText className={classes.navLink}>{item.label}</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
              </NavLink>
              )}
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
       </div>
      </Router>
```

**Page with tabs**

```
    function TabPanel(props) {
        const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
      
        return (
          <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
          >
            {value === index && (
              <Box p={0} sx={{boxShadow: 2}}>
                <>{children}</>
              </Box>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    
   const MyPage = () => {
      const subNav = [
        "Tab 1",
        "Tab 2",
        "Tab 3",
        "Tab 4"
      ]
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
      const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      };

    return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
              <Tabs value={value} TabIndicatorProps={{
               style: { background: '#333333', height: "2px" }
             }} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="tabs">
                  {subNav.map((item, i) => 
                    <Tab key={i} label={`${item}`} /> 
                  )}
              </Tabs>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              Content of tab 1
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
              Content of tab 2
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
              Content of tab 3
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
              Content of tab 4
            </TabPanel>
          </div>
     )
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding the urlParam to the deps array of the `useEffect` ?

Comment: @LuisGurmendez - yes, but that has no effect